# Where do I find the schema for .NET v2.0.50727 (SP2) machine.config file on XP?

Tags: .net, schema, windows-xp-sp2

Where do I find the schema for .NET v2.0.50727 (SP2) machine.config file on XP?

Answer (score -1):

MSDN is a good place to start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fk1t1t0(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Found that 10 minutes into the problem....... But, if I want to validate an .xml I need the actual schema file. Didn't see that on the page, just a bunch of documentation.